# How to find media file type using MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType like mp3/mpeg/m4a in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, mpmediaitem, mpmediapickercontroller

I am developing a music app in Swift3. Where I need to select any audio song from device gallery and upload this to Amazon S3. Here is my code :

```
    func mediaPicker(_ mediaPicker: MPMediaPickerController, didPickMediaItems mediaItemCollection: MPMediaItemCollection)
    {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        let item: MPMediaItem? = (mediaItemCollection.items[0] as? MPMediaItem)

        let url: URL? = item?.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL) as! URL?
        let albumTitle = item?.value( forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle ) as! String
        let albumMediaType = item?.value( forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType) as! Int

}
```

As an output, I am getting Asset Url : ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=8739819345820495362 And Media Type is coming in integer 1/2/3/4....

Now, my problem is I need to know the file type of the selected song, because when I am adding hard code '.mp3' to file and upload this to Amazon S3 then some of audio files are playing and rest is not!

Can you please help me out to resolve this issue? Thank you.

Edit: Here is my code to convert AssetUrl to path :

```
func exportMedia(_ assetURL: URL, completionHandler: @escaping (_ fileURL: URL?, _ error: Error?) -> ()) {
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: assetURL)
        guard let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: asset, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A) else {
            completionHandler(nil, ExportError.unableToCreateExporter)
            return
        }

        let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
            .appendingPathComponent(NSUUID().uuidString)
            .appendingPathExtension("m4a")

        exporter.outputURL = fileURL
        exporter.outputFileType = "com.apple.m4a-audio"

        exporter.exportAsynchronously {
            if exporter.status == .completed {
                completionHandler(fileURL, nil)
            } else {
                completionHandler(nil, exporter.error)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can get the extension from the Asset URL. I don't see where the problem is

Comment: This is my Asset Url : ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=8739819345820495362, you mean .mp3 is file type?

Comment: Yes. You can it by converting the asset url to `URL` and then using `pathExtension`

Comment: @Lefteris what should I give for appendingPathExtension?, please see my updated question. Thanks

Comment: You can get the `audiovisualTypes` for the asset and from there you know the file format: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avfiletype

Comment: Thanks for your reference link, this is like supported formats. In my case how can I find at run time?

Comment: I am getting this Print : <AVAssetExportSession: 0x1700165f0, asset = <AVURLAsset: 0x17023d880, URL = ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=4326775925051828625>, presetName = AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A, outputFileType = (null)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160277/discussion-between-anand-gautam-and-lefteris).